# "Write after end": how to imitate gulp-watch with watchify?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, node-streams, watchify

The following Gulp task does *almost* what I want.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const vinylStream = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const vinylBuffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
const watchify = require('watchify');
const glob = require('glob');
const jasmineBrowser = require('gulp-jasmine-browser');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    let testBundler = browserify({
        entries: glob.sync('src/**/*-test.js'),
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
    }).plugin(watchify);
    function updateSpecs() {
        return testBundler.bundle()
            .pipe(vinylStream(jsBundleName))
            .pipe(vinylBuffer())
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({console: true}))
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless({driver: 'phantomjs'}));
    }
    testBundler.on('update', updateSpecs);
    updateSpecs();
});
```

It bundles all my Jasmine specs using Browserify and has them tested through [gulp-jasmine-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine-browser). It also watches all specs and all modules that they depend on and re-runs the tests if any of these modules changes.

The only ugly bit, which I'd really like to see solved, is that a new PhantomJS instance and a new Jasmine server are created every time `updateSpecs` is run. I was hoping to avoid that with code like the following:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
    let testBundler = browserify({
        entries: glob.sync('src/**/*-test.js'),
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
    }).plugin(watchify);
    // persist the Jasmine server and PhantomJS browser
    let testServer = jasmineBrowser.headless({driver: 'phantomjs'});
    function updateSpecs() {
        return testBundler.bundle()
            .pipe(vinylStream(jsBundleName))
            .pipe(vinylBuffer())
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({console: true}))
            .pipe(testServer);
    }
    testBundler.on('update', updateSpecs);
    updateSpecs();
});
```

Alas, this doesn't work. Right after starting the task, all tests run fine, but the next time `updateSpecs` is called, I get a `write after end` error and the task exits with status 1. This error originates from the `readable-stream` Node module.

As I understand it, the `end` event during the first run of `updateSpecs` leaves `testServer` in a state in which it doesn't accept any new inputs. Unfortunately, the [Node.js streams documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) isn't very clear on how to remedy this.

I have tried breaking the pipe chain at a different place, but I got the same result, which seems to indicate this is universal behaviour for streams. I also tried stopping the `end` event from propagating by inserting a through-stream that didn't re-emit that event, but this prevented the tests from being run at all. Finally, I tried `return`ing the `testServer` stream from the task; this stopped the error, but although the `updateSpecs` function gets called every time the sources change, the tests are only being run the first time the task starts. This time, the `testServer` simply seems to ignore the new input.

The gulp-jasmine-browser documentation suggests that the following code would work:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    var filesForTest = ['src/**/*.js', 'spec/**/*-test.js'];
    return gulp.src(filesForTest)
        .pipe(watch(filesForTest))
        .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
        .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server());
});
```

And it goes on to suggest that you can also make this work with Browserify, but this isn't illustrated. Apparently, gulp-watch does something which causes the follow-up pipes to accept updated inputs later. How can I imitate this behaviour with watchify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/jasmine/gulp-jasmine-browser/issues/22)

As it turns out, it is a hard rule in Node.js that you cannot write after the `end` event. In addition, `jasmineBrowser.specRunner()`, `.server()` and `.headless()` *must* receive the `end` signal in order to actually test anything. This restriction is inherited from the official Jasmine test runner.

The example with `gulp-watch` from the README doesn't actually work, either, for the same reason. In order to make it work, one would have to do something similar to the working version of my `watchify` code in the question:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
    var filesForTest = ['src/**/*.js', 'spec/**/*-test.js'];
    function runTests() {
        return gulp.src(filesForTest)
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server());
    }
    watch(filesForTest).on('add change unlink', runTests);
});
```

(I didn't test it, but something very close to this should work.)

So whatever watching mechanism you're using, you'll always need to call `.specRunner()` and `.server()` again for every cycle. The good news is that apparently, the Jasmine server will be reused if you explicitly pass a port number:

```
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server({port: 8080}));
```

this also applies to `.headless()`.